# Make a real SVG feDropShadow shadow from CSS filter:drop-shadow()?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm wondering is it a way to transpile CSS `drop-shadow` into the pure SVG one `feDropShadow` by hands or some environment maybe?

Like for this example:

```
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 0.1px #fff) drop-shadow(0px 1px 3px #a3d900de);
```

The thing like below is not works:

```
<filter id="some_id">
  <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="1" stdDeviation=".1" flood-color="#fff" />
  <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="1" stdDeviation="3" flood-color="#a3d900de" />
</filter>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But it works. Try adding this to your svg: `<rect x="75" y="25" height="100" width="100" stroke="#000" fill="#6ab150" filter="url(#some_id)"></rect>`

Answer (score 2):

This is the sort of question that you could have answered yourself by looking up the definition of the `drop-shadow()` filter function in the CSS specification.

The definition is here:

https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#dropshadowEquivalent

Alternatively, it is also described on MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#drop-shadow()_2

Comment: If you look at the examples in MDN, you can see that it doesn't look exactly the same. The SVG shadow does not spread as far. If you increase the size of the stdDeviation, it ends up being a lighter shadow.